# Forced to use getsupport functions with API 14+

Tags: android, android-support-library

I read that getSupportFragmentManager (and other getSupport functions) were created for the sake of Android versions under Honeycomb (3.0). Such equivalent functions for API 11+ are getFragmentManager (and other functions without getSupport).

I started a new project with minSdkVersion="14" and targetSdkVersion="15". In folder libs, I can see android-support-v4.jar which should not be there since the min SDK version is 14.
Besides, I tried to use getFragmentManager but it is not recognized at all (I can't compile).
So, I have no choice but to use getSupportManagerFragment...

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, getFragmentManager() is available on API level 11+. If you don't need classes from the support library, you can delete the support-v4.jar from your libs folder and make your activities extend Activity instead of FragmentActivity.

If you are not using the support library, your imports should not contain "support.v4.app" in them.

Thanks for a tip from @Espiandev, if you select the "Tab+swipe application" template in Eclipse, then it will automatically include the support library because this template uses the ViewPager class which only exists in the support library.

Comment: It's not that you "should not use them"... it's more that it's not necessary. The app won't break if you use the support libraries on new devices...

Comment: It's probably there if you've selected "Tab+swipe application" or a similar template. The ViewPager class is currently incompatible with the non-support Fragment system.

Comment: @Espiandev yeah, that's probably it.

Comment: @Espiandev yeah that could be it. didn't know that eclipse has these templates.

Comment: Indeed, I selected "Tab+swipe application", so I  will keep the support library. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse probably added the support library to your build path automatically when you created the project, which is why it isn't recognizing `getFragmentManager`. Although unnecessary, it's perfectly fine to use the support libraries on an application with a `minSdkVersion` greater than or equal to `11`. In fact, you might even consider doing so, as it will make supporting older devices much easier for you later on.

Comment: Including the support library will potentially increase the size of your binary, so you probably should not include it if you don't need it.

My understanding is that having the support library does not block you from calling getFragmentManager if your minSdkVersion supports it and you have the native classes imports (the ones without support.v4.app in their fully-qualified names). Right?